# Building a custom JSON array from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I'm getting a list of a user's friends from both facebook's and twitter's API.

```
var facebook_friends = { "data": [{"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123"}, {"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342"}]}
var twitter_friends = { "users": [{"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333"}, {"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456"}]}
```

And i want to build an array like this(Nb: i'm appending the provider key to identify the source of the data)

```
var all_friends = [{"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123", "provider": "facebook"},{"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342", "provider": "facebook"}, {"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333", "provider": "twitter"},{"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456", "provider": "twitter"}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var facebook_friends = { "data": [{"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123"}, {"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342"}]};

$.map(facebook_friends.data, function($item) {
    $item['provider'] = 'facebook';
    return $item;    
});

var twitter_friends = { "users": [{"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333"}, {"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456"}]};

$.map(twitter_friends.users, function($item) {
    $item['provider'] = 'twitter';
    return $item;    
});

var all_friends = $.merge(facebook_friends.data, twitter_friends.users);

console.log(all_friends);
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3jJ/)**

Comment: Thanks @martynas, do you know how to add the provider key in each array?

Comment: Like in the all_friends variable

Comment: aaaah, didn't notice that. give me a minute